# Call async method from property setter

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a couple of places where I do this, but it's not feasible/practical to rework the code. However it seems that the method can just be called "normally", e.g.:-

```
set
{
    ...
    DoSomethingAsync();
}
```

A squiggle appears in the VS editor under this line, with this tooltip warning:-

> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed.

Without the async/await keywords I kind of expected that the method would end up being called *synchronously*. What am I not getting here?

If I change the line to the following then the squiggle/warning disappears:-

```
DoSomethingAsync().Wait();
```

Presumably this turns it into a blocking call?

And purely out of curiosity, what would be the implications of doing the following:-

```
Task.Run(() => DoSomethingAsync());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Without the async/await keywords I kind of expected that the method would end up being called synchronously. What am I not getting here?

Your assumption is wrong: an `async` method is *always* called asynchronously. Unless you `Wait()` it, it will not wait until the `async` method is done. `Wait()` will indeed block the call to your async method. Even if you do `Task.Run`, it will run asynchonously (twice, since it `async` method runs asynchronously within your `Task.Run`).

Properties can't be called asynchronously, so a `Get` method would do the trick here. That way you can make your code asynchronous all the way.

Answer (score 6):

### **Call Async method within a property setter (MVVM usage)**

**Create the method**

```
public class AsyncRunner
{
    public static void Run(Task task, Action<Task> onError = null)
    {
        if (onError == null)
        {
            task.ContinueWith((task1, o) => { }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        }
        else
        {
            task.ContinueWith(onError, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Call it within a setter property**

```
private NavigationMenuItem _selectedMenuItem;
public NavigationMenuItem SelectedMenuItem
{
    get { return _selectedMenuItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedMenuItem = val;
        AsyncRunner.Run(YourAsyncMethod(_selectedMenuItem));            
    }
}
```

---

**This is the async method that needs to be run...**

```
private async Task YourAsyncMethod(NavigationMenuItem newNavigationMenu)
{
    //call async tasks...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the definition of DoSomethingAsync() it will be something like this

```
   public async Task<T> DoSomethingAsync()
   public       Task<T> DoSomethingAsync()
```

Either way, it will return a Task which has (probably) only just started.

You can either call .Wait() on the task, or not.

If not, you are leaving that Task to run in the background.

That's probably not the programmer's intention - hence the warning.